# Spring-ldap configuration issue

Tags: configuration, spring-ldap

I am trying to configure a spring-ldap context source and I find the following example in the documentation:

```
   <ldap:context-source
          username="cn=Administrator"
          password="secret"
          url="ldap://localhost:389"
          base="dc=261consulting,dc=com" />
```

I would like to be able to specify the userid/password and, if possible, the url and port elsewhere (like a JNDI reference from a datasource). I can't find any context source example or spec in the documentation (or in google) that has this sort of configuration. Can I do it and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beyond using a properties file, no.

Answer (score 0):

You can instantiate the class: **`org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource`** internally in your application and then set the values: url, base, userDn, password, referral, etc.

In the [**spring-ldap samples**](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ldap/tree/master/samples) you will find how to use it. [**Here**](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ldap/blob/9a524c3d7dae7d40c47b9a88813a3222e63602dd/core/src/test/java/org/springframework/ldap/core/support/LdapContextSourceTest.java) is an example!

I hope it helps!

Comment: This is what I'm doing now. I was hoping for a way to really put it at arms length like you can do with a datasource and JNDI.